# Is there a time limit to run workflow automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We had used workflow designer to create workflows to manage projects phases. However, we have some projects that are more than a year in the same phase (execution) and when you want to move the workflow to the next stage it is not working. is there a time limit to run workflow automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to create workflow for each phase of project and create a conditional start: When state equals Phase 1 - run WF1, if Phase 2 - run WF2 ..... etc...

There are probably some limits in online, but I havent found any documentation for this (somebody asked in past for the same question)

Comment: This is the correct way.  Make flags in your list to change that will initiate the next step.  Pausing WFs is a terrible idea.  Plus, with the asynchronous nature of SP, they will never fire from the timer job as expected and you will have failed WF jobs stuck running in the background.